# Discord.js how to fetch message by content

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I trying to make a code that fetch messages and filter them with content but it don’t work. I try this code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content.startsWith('f-')){
        var wf = message.content.substring(2);
        message.channel.send(`message id: ${message.channel.messages.fetch().filter(mc => mc.startsWith(wf))}`);
    }
});
```

But it gives that error: **message.channel.messages.fetch(...).filter is not a function** so i wanna ask is there a way to fetch messages by id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`message.channel.messages.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetch) returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and if you want to get the result you have `await` it. When you have fetched all messages you can go on and filter them by the `msg.content`.

The following code gives you all messages that start with "f-":

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("f-")) {
    var wf = message.content.substring(2);

    const messages = await message.channel.messages.fetch();
    let filtered = messages.filter((msg) => msg.content.startsWith(wf));
    console.log(filtered);
  }
});
```